# fopen() with path as a variable

Tags: c

Trying to open file in a relative path,
Path is different everytime, I want to use a char as path

Currently I have:

```
char path[128];
strcat(path, "/home/pi/Analyses/");
strcat(path, lstAnalyse);
strcat(path, "/data.txt");
fopen(path, "a");
```

What is the right way to use a char as path with fopen ?

Comment: First `strcat` is UB as `path` is uninitialized. Replace it with `strcpy`. Or simply initialize `path` with the first string...

Comment: Either change `strcat(path, "/home/pi/Analyses/");` to `strcpy(path, "/home/pi/Analyses/");`, or change `char path[128];` to `char path[128] = "";`.